# How to mock application configuration or context for @springboottest?

Tags: java, spring-boot-test

I have an app that requires external connection (database, config server, analytics server) to boot up.

When I run ‘@springboottest’, I do not want to connect to the real url, therefore the app cannot boot for testing. What’s the best way to solve the issue?

Is there a way to provide mock before the app starts?

Answer (score 2):

`@MockBean` is what you are looking for. It is used to replace a bean with a Mockito mock. An example from the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.testing.spring-boot-applications.mocking-beans) is :

```
@SpringBootTest
class MyTests {

    @Autowired
    private Reverser reverser;

    @MockBean
    private RemoteService remoteService;

    @Test
    void exampleTest() {
        given(this.remoteService.getValue()).willReturn("spring");
        String reverse = this.reverser.getReverseValue(); // Calls injected RemoteService
        assertThat(reverse).isEqualTo("gnirps");
    }

}
```

Also using `@SpringBootTest` without further configuration by default will load all beans defined in the application which may be too much for testing as normally we only focus on testing one thing in each test.

So if you are not testing the controller layer or the data layer , most probably you can rewrite your test as the plain Mockito test without using `@SpringBootTest`. It is simpler and also run faster.

For testing the controller layer or the data layer , please check out `@WebMvcTest` , `@DataJpaTest` , `@JdbcTest`  , `@DataJdbcTest` etc. (Refer the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.testing.spring-boot-applications.autoconfigured-tests) for details)